# Pod is stuck in PodInitializing status when an initContainer is OOMKilled

Tags: kubernetes, nvidia, gpu, containerd

I have the following on-prem Kubernetes environment:

- OS: Red Hat Enterprise Linux release 8.6 (Ootpa)
- Kubernetes: 1.23.7 (single-node, build with kubeadm)
- NVIDIA driver: 515.65.01
- nvidia-container-toolkit: 1.10.0-1.x86_64 (rpm)
- containerd: v1.6.2
- vcr.io/nvidia/k8s-device-plugin:v0.12.2

And I run the following Pod on my server. Only app2 (initContainer2) uses GPU.

```
initContainer1: app1
↓
initContainer2: app2 (Uses GPU)
↓
container1: app3
```

When the app2 uses too much RAM and is OOM killed, the Pod should be in the `OOMKilled` status, but it's stuck in the `PodInitializing` status on my environment.

```
NAMESPACE     NAME       READY   STATUS            RESTARTS       AGE     IP               NODE      NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
default       gpu-pod    0/1     PodInitializing   0              83m     xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx   xxxxx   <none>           <none>
```

The results of `kubectl describe pod` is as follows:

```
Init Containers:
  app1:
    ...
    State:          Terminated
      Reason:       Completed
      Exit Code:    0
      Started:      Tue, 30 Aug 2022 10:50:38 +0900
      Finished:     Tue, 30 Aug 2022 10:50:44 +0900
      ...
app2:
    ...
    State:          Terminated
      Reason:       OOMKilled
      Exit Code:    0
      Started:      Tue, 30 Aug 2022 10:50:45 +0900
      Finished:     Tue, 30 Aug 2022 10:50:48 +0900
      ...
app3:
    ...
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       PodInitializing
      ...
    ...
```

This problem will never happen when I replace app2 with another container that doesn't use GPU, or when I launch app2 as a single container (not an init Container) of the Pod. In both cases, the status will be properly `OOMKilled`.

Is this a bug? If so, are there any workarounds?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So workflow is like below from documentation.

Init containers are exactly like regular containers, except:

- Init containers always run to completion.
- Each init container must complete successfully before the next one starts.

If a Pod's init container fails, the kubelet repeatedly restarts that init container until it succeeds. However, if the Pod has a restartPolicy of Never, and an init container fails during startup of that Pod, Kubernetes treats the overall Pod as failed.

So it's in correct state AFAIK.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The status of the Pod when app2 is OOMKilled depends on which container is used as app2. What causes this difference? Exit codes when OOMKilled?

Comment: Please check this https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/104650/files, It should mark init container failed though I see return status is 0, it might be how you write script for init or how it used.

Comment: It seems the app2's non-init process was OOMKilled and the init process didn't recognize that. Thanks!